# CloudFormation Fn::Transform Operation: Lower -> syntax error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to create an AWS S3 Bucket with cloud formation.

S3 bucket name needs to be lowercase but I want to use a paramenter to compound that name. This parameter comes uppercase.

I founded a way.

I read this.

- https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cloudformation-templates/tree/master/aws/services/CloudFormation/MacrosExamples/StringFunctions

This is my code:

```yaml
Parameters:

# Global
  ServiceName:
    Type: String
    Description: 'Service Name'
    Default: content-input
   
  Environment:
    Type: String
    Description: 'Environment Name'

Resources:
  S3Bucket: 
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: !Join ['-',
      [ 
        content-input,
        'Fn::Transform':
          - Name: 'String'
          Parameters: 
            InputString: !Ref Environment
            Operation: Lower
      ]]
```

But I get this error.

```sh
while parsing a flow node
expected the node content, but found '-'
  in "<unicode string>", line 157, column 11:
              - Name: 'String'
```

I tried this other syntax referered [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-transform.html)

```yaml
Parameters:

# Global
  ServiceName:
    Type: String
    Description: 'Service Name'
    Default: content-input
   
  Environment:
    Type: String
    Description: 'Environment Name'

Resources:
  S3Bucket: 
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: !Join ['-',
      [ 
        content-input,
        'Fn::Transform':
          Name: 'String'
          Parameters: 
            InputString: !Ref Environment
            Operation: Lower
      ]]
```

But I get:

```sh
while parsing a flow sequence
  in "<unicode string>", line 154, column 7:
          [
          ^
expected ',' or ']', but got ':'
  in "<unicode string>", line 157, column 15:
              Name: 'String'
                  ^
```

Of Course, this work perfectly.

```yaml
Parameters:

# Global
  ServiceName:
    Type: String
    Description: 'Service Name'
    Default: content-input
   
  Environment:
    Type: String
    Description: 'Environment Name'

Resources:
  S3Bucket: 
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: !Join ['-',
      [ 
        content-input,
        mytext
      ]]
```

How is the right syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Important point to note to get the syntax right is to use Json with Yaml when using multiple Intrinsic functions.
Updated syntax below. For Environment value `DEV`, this creates a bucket of name `content-input-dev`

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Parameters:
  ServiceName:
    Type: String
    Description: "Service Name"
    Default: content-input
  Environment:
    Type: String
    Description: "Environment Name"
Resources:
  S3Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName:
        !Join [
          "-",
          [
            !Ref ServiceName,
            {
              "Fn::Transform":
                {
                  "Name": "String",
                  "Parameters":
                    { "InputString": !Ref Environment, "Operation": "Lower" },
                },
            },
          ],
        ]
```

Comment: With this code I get "Failed to create the changeset: Waiter ChangeSetCreateComplete failed: Waiter encountered a terminal failure state Status: FAILED. Reason: No transform named <MY AWS ACCOUNT NUMBER>::String found."

Comment: @icalvete The answer is correct. You are getting the error since you probably do not have string macro.

Comment: @Marcin, Before aprove an answer, I prefer test it all. I think mi code is working too, so the real problem is no the syntax. The real problem is I don't have the string macro (As you said) I don't even kwon what is that. I'm going to read about it and then test it. I thought approve the answer then. But, in your honnor, I just approved. Thanks.

Comment: @icalvete No problem. String macro is porvided by [this](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cloudformation-templates/blob/master/aws/services/CloudFormation/MacrosExamples/StringFunctions/string.yaml) template. So you have to deploy it beforehand.

Comment: @icalvete In question cloudformation threw error during validation, once syntax is correct , it tried to create a changeSet and failed with `String` transform is missing.